# How to reconstruct the hierarchy of multi-index data frame after read_sql?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-index data frame originally looking like this (sorry for the image format - more on that later):

[image]

This data frame is stored into a SQLite table. When I use `read_sql_query` specifying `index_col=['id', 'year', 'interval']`, I obtain a version of the data frame where the column names are flattened:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"('LSSR.EVI', 'anomaly')": {('102003425432342620301682804267026993600',
   2010,
   15): -1.2427875479709378,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 16): -1.5810953949599622,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 17): -0.21514085140646852,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 18): 2.8447636755956602,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 19): 5.387294849602293},
 "('LSSR.EVI', 'delta')": {('102003425432342620301682804267026993600',
   2010,
   15): -0.08247779546308173,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 16): -0.13964240787494409,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 17): -0.14732367140515223,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 18): -0.048977311394384104,
  ('102003425432342620301682804267026993600', 2010, 19): 0.12874585657790194}})
df.index.rename(['id','year','interval'], inplace=True)
```

As you can see, the two levels of hierarchy on the columns have been flattened - i.e. in parentheses and separated by a comma. The reason for the image above is that I realised that exporting a data frame with `to_dict` produces the same result and I didn't know how to share it on SO, but hopefully the other df will be sufficient to get the problem. My questions are:

1. How can I reconstruct the hierarchy of the original data frame? I have tried `.unstack()`, but it seems to somehow only work on `axis=0`
2. What does the nomenclature ('col1', 'col2') actually represent and what is the way to access the different columns? I have tried many combinations of `df['LSSR.EVI']`, `df[('LSSR.EVI')]`, `df[('LSSR.EVI', 'anomaly')]` but they all return errors and I have the feeling that I am missing a critical logical step here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import ast

#if strings tuples in columns
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df.columns])
#if tuples in columns
#df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples df.columns.tolist())
print (df)
                                                       LSSR.EVI          
                                                        anomaly     delta
id                                      year interval                    
102003425432342620301682804267026993600 2010 15       -1.242788 -0.082478
                                             16       -1.581095 -0.139642
                                             17       -0.215141 -0.147324
                                             18        2.844764 -0.048977
                                             19        5.387295  0.128746
```

Now is possible select columns by tuples:

```
print (df[('LSSR.EVI', 'anomaly')])
id                                       year  interval
102003425432342620301682804267026993600  2010  15         -1.242788
                                               16         -1.581095
                                               17         -0.215141
                                               18          2.844764
                                               19          5.387295
Name: (LSSR.EVI, anomaly), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Do I take that there is no easy way of accessing the columns with the ('col1', 'col2') - i.e. regarding the second part of my question?

Comment: @e5k - Then not working `df[('LSSR.EVI', 'anomaly')]` ?It should be

Comment: I get `KeyError: ('LSSR.EVI', 'anomaly')`